# jquery vertical nav - slideUp slideDown

Tags: jquery, navigation, slidedown, slideup

i use this html structure:

```
    <div id="products">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 2 b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and this jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#products li").click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'selected') {
            $('#products li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
    });


    $("#products li").click(function() {
        $('#products li ul').slideUp();
        $('#products li.selected ul').slideDown();

    });

});
```

Problem:

i only want to have the slide up and down effect on items of the first level (< li >)
not on the sub-items

an other problem - if the list item is already class="selected" and you click on it it slides up and then again down.. (nothing should happen if it is already )

can someone help with the jquery code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LEdgT/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#products > ul > li").click(function() {
        if ($(this).has('ul')) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).removeClass('selected')
                       .find('ul').slideUp();
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass('selected')
                       .find('ul').slideDown();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to `$('#products > ul > li')`, it would select only the immediate children.

---

Or you could change the entire code to something more readable and less repetetive:

```
var $topLevelItems = $("#products > ul > li");

$topLevelItems.click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $topLevelItems.removeClass('selected')
                      .find('ul')
                      .slideUp();

        $(this).addClass('selected')
               .find('ul')
               .slideDown();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `:not` selector or `.not`

```
    $('#products > li:not(.selected)').click(function() {
        $('#products li ul').slideUp();
        $('#products li.selected ul').slideDown();
    });
```